# Change a Fahrenheit character into celcius character

Tags: jquery

[image]

I want to achieve this, When I click the Fahrenheit character,It will change into  Celcius character.But not work, How to make it?

```
<html lang="en">
```

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "&#8457;") {
    $(this).html("&#8451;");
  } else {
    $(this).html("&#8457;");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owfont-regular.css">
<a id="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">&#8457;</a>
```

Comment: `if($(this).text() == '℉')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "℉") {
    $(this).text("℃");
  } else {
    $(this).text("℉");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">℉</a>
```

So does this

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var temp = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(temp == "℉"?"℃":"℉");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">℉</a>
```

Comment: @actx: and this is the correct comparison (using the actual unicode characters) :)

Comment: The Fahrenheit character can be entered directly?

Comment: @Gaby: There is a key sequence to enter any Unicode character. Worst case: Alt + (numpad) then the value digits of the characters.

Comment: You can also use `"\u2109"` (hex 2109 = decimal 8457) to put the character in a javascript string while keeping the source code as ASCII. And use `&#x2109;` in the HTML so the equivalence is obvious.

Comment: @Gone Coding  but why my previous code didn't work,is there any mistake I made?

Comment: Comparing text with HTML

Comment: @mplungjan But if I change the .text() method into .html(), it still won't work?

Comment: Console log the entity and you will see it is converted to a char before you compare

Comment: @Gaby: your code was fine, but it was comparing `&#8451;` in HTML which is stored as a single Unicode character. To have the same character in a Javascript string requires a different sort of encoding to produce the same character it will match.

Comment: @GoneCoding Got it!

Comment: To get the char, I copied it from the snippet when it rendered